# Can assign Child for Parent in Query DSL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

there QParent, QChild1, and QChild2
I try to use QParent instead of each child.

the class that contains all predicates

```
class Filter {
        private QParent query;

        public Filter(QParent query) {
            this.query = query;
        }

       BooleanExpression getPredicates(String name) {
          name == null ? null : query.name.eq(name);
          return query.isNotNull().and(name);
    }
}
```

then I send a child as an argument for the Filter constructor

```
  childOneRepo.findAll(new Filter(QChild1.child1).getPredicates("test name"));
```

but `new Filter(QChild1.child1)` give me an error.

although child1 and child2 extend the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the entities extend each other, the query types do not. Instead, you ahve to use `new Filter(QChild1.child1._super)`.

Comment: Thanx Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling I think I tried this solution but let me test it again if good so it will be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanx, it already works.
please check this question it obstacles me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286170/wrong-result-metadata-when-using-pagination-with-balze-persistence