# Wrong result metadata when using pagination with Balze-Persistence

Tags: java, mysql, spring, querydsl, blaze-persistence

When I fetch all results without pagination result is OK but when use pagination appear problem in pagination metadata

```
Page p=PageImpl(result.getResults(), PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize), result.getTotal()) 
p.getTotalElements() // wrong result
p.result.getTotalPages() // also is wrong
```

code snippet:-

```
QOrderAppliedTax qTax = QOrderAppliedTax.orderAppliedTax;
        QOrderDetails qOrderDetails = QOrderDetails.orderDetails;

        NumberExpression<Integer> groupBy = qOrderDetails.createdDate.yearWeek();
        StringPath name = qTax.name;
        NumberExpression<Double> totalTaxValue = qTax.value.sum();
        NumberExpression<Long> ordersCount = qOrderDetails.order.countDistinct();
        DateTimeExpression<Date> fromDate = qOrderDetails.createdDate.min();
        DateTimeExpression<Date> toDate = qOrderDetails.createdDate.max();

        CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf = Criteria.getDefault().createCriteriaBuilderFactory(entityManagerFactory);

        QueryResults<TaxDto> result= new BlazeJPAQuery<>(em, cbf)
                .select(Projections.constructor(TaxDto.class, fromDate, toDate, groupBy, name, totalTaxValue,
                        ordersCount))

                .from(qTax).innerJoin(qOrderDetails).on(qTax.orderDetails.eq(qOrderDetails))

                .groupBy(taxName, groupBy).offset(pageNo * pageSize).limit(pageSize).fetchResults();
```

the wrong result appears even I used

```
orderBy(groupBy.asc(), taxName.asc())
```

exactly the two fields in order by is unique together.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? What values are you passing in and what values do you get? Also, please post the generated SQL query.

Comment: Thanx @Christian Beikov for replying.
I grouped by two fileds "taxName, groupBy" the query that brings data is OK but when investigated the count query I found that it  "select count(distinct taxName)" taxName only without groupBy so exactly getTotalElements() will be wrong.

Comment: Could you try `.page(pageNo * pageSize, pageSize)` instead of `offset(pageNo * pageSize).limit(pageSize).fetchResults()`? That uses Blaze-Persistence to generate the pagination instead. I think I might incorrectly pass on the limit and offset to the count query for the `fetchResults` implementation.

Comment: I already did that and it is similar to the offset and limit no difference. The total rows are not correct and also total pages.

The difference is count query does not appear.

Comment: What are the used values for `pageNo` and `pageSize`, and the expected and actual results for `getTotalElements` and `getTotalPages`? Could you also provide the produced query (`BlazeJPAQuery.getQueryString`)? I think these are all the info I need to reproduce and fix the issue.

Comment: `.page` was supposed to be `.fetchPage` in my previous answer.

Comment: How is `taxName` defined? I only see `StringPath name` in the code. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Comment length is limited so it has two parts.
Part1:- 
-----------
SELECT min(orderDetails.createdDate), max(orderDetails.createdDate), date_format(orderDetails.createdDate,'%Y-%m'), orderAppliedTax.name, sum(orderAppliedTax.value), COUNT(DISTINCT order_1) FROM OrderAppliedTax orderAppliedTax JOIN OrderDetails orderDetails ON (orderAppliedTax.orderDetails = orderDetails) LEFT JOIN orderDetails.order order_1 GROUP BY orderAppliedTax.name, date_format(orderDetails.createdDate,'%Y-%m'), CASE WHEN date_format(orderDetails.createdDate,'%Y-%m') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: Part2:-
, CASE WHEN orderAppliedTax.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY CASE WHEN date_format(orderDetails.createdDate,'%Y-%m') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, date_format(orderDetails.createdDate,'%Y-%m') ASC, CASE WHEN orderAppliedTax.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, orderAppliedTax.name ASC

Comment: Field ```taxName``` is String datatype but I use QueryDSL with Blaze.

Comment: The queries look ok so far considering that `taxName` and `groupBy` are nullable. How does the count query look like?

Comment: You can find the count query string through `BlazeJPAQuery.getFullQueryBuilder(null).getCountQueryString()`.

Comment: Feel free to join the Blaze-Persistence and Querydsl slack groups if you run into further issues: https://join.slack.com/t/querydsl/shared_invite/zt-r7ufzz6q-zxIHgpOSSMFvoU3YU4SclQ and https://join.slack.com/t/blazebit/shared_invite/zt-wkbkpx28-xA01ZFLM7UXdp9FfttAQ5A

Comment: I can't found ```getFullQueryBuilder(null)``` method.

Comment: ```taxName``` and ```groupBy``` are nullable.
How can I test this they never be null?

Comment: Why when using ```offset``` and ```limit```  generate this query?
select count(distinct orderappli0_.name) as col_0_0_ from order_applied_tax orderappli0_ inner join order_details orderdetai1_ on (orderappli0_.order_details_id=orderdetai1_.id).   
Note that:- 
```count(distinct orderappli0_.name)``` count by name only despite ```groupBy``` name and date

Comment: It could be because `taxName` is assumed to be unique (for example if its mapped as primary key). If `taxName` is unique and `groupBy` is a property on the same query root, there's would be no need to consider the additional `groupBy` alias. However, these properties come from different query roots, so I suspect this is a count query generation issue in Blaze-Persistence. I'll try to create a reproducer there, so we can look into it further. (https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/pulls)

Comment: No ```taxName```is not unique it is repeatable.

Comment: Ideally, you would mark the columns as "nullable = false" or use `coalesce(.., someConstant)` to avoid these "additional" order by and group by items that handle nullability.

Answer (score 1):

This issue turned out to be [a bug](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1366) which will be resolved in Blaze-Persistence 1.6.3 (expected soon). The patch has already landed in `1.6.3-SNAPSHOT`.